# convert int to hex string <sstream>

Tags: c++

I have an int number as 0x30, when I convert to string it will return "48".
But what I want is "30"

```
int var = 0x30;
std::string text = std::to_string(var);
```

Comment: `int var = 0x30;` **is** `int var = 48;`.

Comment: of course it is. but that's not my question (see answer below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `std::stringstream`

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    int var = 0x30;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::hex << var;
    std::string text = ss.str();
}
```